# Does my graphic just died?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure

### Problem description

Today, ma screen just turned black, back and then the computer was frozen. After restart, there were some weird characters on screen (about 2 seconds) and then normal screens during booting (before starting OS). Windows started, but only at lower resolution and one of my two monitors remained black (without signal). When I looked at the device manager, there was an error with the graphic card.

> Systém Windows zastavil toto zariadenie, pretože zariadenie ohlásilo
>   problémy. (Kód 43)
>   Windows stopped this deivce, because it has reported problems (code 43)

*Boot up screens*
[image: Bootup 1]
[image: Bootup 2]
[image: Bootup 3]

After few restarts, all worked without any problem, I got full resolution. Then I've run game and again screens turned black.

Now my computer runs at lower resolution with only one monitor and error at graphic card at device manager.

```
Graphic card: Nvidia GT9800 1GB  
Mainboard: ASUS P5Q3  
Computer age: about 5-6 years
```

---

### Question

Did my graphic card die or not? If so, how is that possible my computer (*windows*) still runs? If I buy new graphic card with two hdmi outputs, can I still use the old (*bad*) graphic card for connecting third monitor?

---

### Update

I've just cleaned up my computer, after start it looked even worse, but then for few another restarts there were no problems at all and now it all looks fine :)

Comment: It is very likely (and yes, a dying card can indeed make the computer seem to "freeze".) It is also possible that just the fan on the card died, which causes it to overheat & fail.  First check the card itself physically to ensure the fan is still working & hasn't become detached. Your description sounds like it was damaged but not completely dead yet.  I would NOT recommend continuing to use it. As for how windows is still running - the graphics card is hardware, and its failure doesn't remove any software that you have installed.

Comment: . . . or dust buildup.  It might also help if the themal interface compound for the heat sink was refreshed also, but that would be after cleaning it and checking the fan and all, and not getting full results.

Comment: @Debra but if graphic card failed, how is that possible my pc is able to display anything using hdmi output ports of *failed* graphic card?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, looks like your graphics card died. If it was a driver issue, you wouldn't see graphical corruption like that on boot.

Answer (score 0):

graphics cards don't make your computer freeze. might be a CPU problem. I see your graphics card is capable of spitting out characters so it's showing it sill works. try using the graphics card on a different machine if possible. OR take it out, sure integrated graphics and check that.

Comment: An overheating graphics card is the first thing to suspect when a computer seems to "freeze" -- it's probably the most common symptom of the hardware issue.